# Copy of a vue.js project folder on MacOS, gives a strange result with vite dev server

Tags: vue.js, vite

On MacOS I was copying the whole directory of a vue.js 3 project:
`cp -rp dir1 dir2`.
However when trying to run a development server in dir2:
`npm run dev`
I got an error:

> (node:98097) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
> (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
>
> /Users/dev/projects/ ... /dir2/node_modules/.bin/vite:2
> import { performance } from 'node:perf_hooks'
> ^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
> at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
> at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:20)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1205:27)
> at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
> at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
> at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47

So I figured, something had to be missing, but I cannot see any difference in the directories, hidden files are copied for sure.
Tried to run: `diff -qr dir1 dir2` and it showed no difference.

However I tried copying the directory via:
`rsync -a dir1/ dir2` which worked fine, and I had no problem and could run the development server on dir2 afterwards.

I realize this question is probably as much about the difference of cp and rsync, than of vue.js and vite, it just beats me that I cannot see a difference in the copied directories, so I wonder what could be the issue.

Comment: You should just remove node_modules and re-run `npm i`

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out that some files in the node_modules/.bin directory are actually symbolic links. These are not followed by the above command `cp -rp dir1 dir2`.

The command to use would be `cp -R dir1 dir2`, which will copy recursively, include hidden files and follow symbolic links